# How can I load in a prefab on trigger so my game keeps going?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a 'run' game in Unity and i'm making a prototype with a ball, that has other balls following him. If the followers hit an object they get destroyed after some time. I made a kind of road with obstacles on them and prefabt them. Now is my question how can i load in a prefab on trigger or something so my game keeps going. The goal is that i dont need to make a whole map but that the map is randomly chosen from prefabs of different roads.

If it would help this is the code for my main character, i tought maybe its in another trigger that you load a prefab or something?

This is my code.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour {

public float InputForce;
public GUIText guiText;
public float rotationHorizontal;
public AudioClip ACeffect2;
public GameObject zombiePrefab;

void FixedUpdate() {

    rigidbody.AddForce( Camera.main.transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * InputForce);
    rigidbody.AddForce( Camera.main.transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * InputForce);

    transform.position += Vector3.forward *InputForce * Time.deltaTime;
    rotationHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * InputForce;
    rotationHorizontal *= Time.deltaTime;
    rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque (Vector3.back * rotationHorizontal);

}

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col){
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Zombie") {
        Debug.Log ("Player geraakt, nu ben je eigenlijk dood");
    }
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Obstakel1") {
        Debug.Log ("Obstakel1 geraakt");
        audio.PlayOneShot(ACeffect2);
        InputForce = 0;
    }
    if (col.gameObject.name == "Obstakel2") {
        Debug.Log ("Obstakel2 geraakt");
    }
}

void AddZombies(int aantal){
    for (int i = 0; i < aantal; i++){
        GameObject go = GameObject.Instantiate(zombiePrefab, transform.position - new Vector3(0, 0, 7 + i),Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        Zombie zb = go.GetComponent<Zombie>();
        zb.target = gameObject.transform;
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) {
    Debug.Log ("Enter" +col.name);
    if (col.tag == "AddZombies"){
        AddZombies(4);
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider col) {
    Debug.Log ("Leaving with" +col.name);
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add gameobject dynamically to scene in Unity3d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500137/add-gameobject-dynamically-to-scene-in-unity3d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a gameobject and add a component containing the following code:

```
public GameObject prefab; // Drag and drop prefab to component in unity

// When trigger is triggered
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col) 
{
    Instantiate(prefab, new Vector3(0,0,0), Quaternion.Identity);
}
```

You can then drag and drop the prefab you want to instantiate to the component in unity.
The position could be where ever you want it to spawn (for example `transform.position` to make it spawn where you have placed your trigger).

Note that to make a trigger you need to make a new empty gameobject and add what ever collider you want to have on it. To make it call the `OnTriggerEnter` method you also need to check the box `is trigger` on the collider component.