# Unity 3D spawn 10 objects on mouseclick

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown ("Fire1")) 
    {

    }
}
```

How do I spawn my prefab on click?

Comment: Your question is not clear, but prefabs can be spawned like this: `GameObject instObj = Instantiate(prefab,transform.TransformPoint(Vector3.forward), Quaternion.identity);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add gameobject dynamically to scene in Unity3d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15500137/add-gameobject-dynamically-to-scene-in-unity3d)

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html

Comment: how do i call my prefab? (called dice) and duplicate it by 10

Comment: e.g. use a for-loop. In the link I have posted there is also a section called "Placing a bunch of objects in a specific pattern". Maybe have a look at it ;)

Comment: well no one answered my question

Comment: Summing up the comments your question has surely been answered. All it takes for you now is to actually do something yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To instantiate a prefab you can use `Instantiate` (as someone told you in a comment) https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

to do that 10 times use a simple for-loop: `for(int i=0; i<10; ++i){ //code }`

so, putting all togheter the update functions can be:

```
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown ("Fire1")) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
            Instantiate(m_oMyPrefab, m_oMyPosition, m_oMyRotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that m_oMyPrefab must be a `GameObject` variable with a reference to your prefab (you can do it programmatically or with the inspector editor),  m_oMyPosition must be a `Vector3` with the desired position and m_oMyRotation must be a `Quaternion`. Position and rotation are optionals, see the documentation for more details.

Comment: it worked. thanks a lot